# Display records in Entity Framework which take list of string as argument

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have created a generic repository which will fetch data from database irrespective of an entity.

In one of the method, I want to retrieve data where I am passing `List<string>` values to check if it present in one column. My code works fine if I pass single value.

Any idea on how to pass `List<string>` in place of `INSTITUTIONID`?

Calling:

```
List<REQUESTDASHBOARD> listDashboard = new List<REQUESTDASHBOARD>();
listDashboard = dashboardSericeManager.GetList(
                d => d.INSTITUTIONID != null &&
                d.INSTITUTIONID.Contains("4cb6d23635"), null).ToList();
```

Implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] navigationProperties)
{
    IEnumerable<T> list;

    var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();

    if (navigationProperties != null && navigationProperties.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(navigationProperty);
        }
    }

    list = query.Where(predicate).ToList<T>();

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed you're defining a `List<string>` collection like this:

```
var institutionList = new List<string>();

// add data into list
institutionList.Add("institutionID_1");
institutionList.Add("institutionID_2"); // etc
```

and `INSTITUTIONID` is a string property inside data model class, then you can use `Any()` & `Contains()` extension methods together to find out `INSTITUTIONID` which available inside above list, similar to `WHERE ... IN ...` query in SQL:

```
List<REQUESTDASHBOARD> listDashboard = new List<REQUESTDASHBOARD>();

listDashboard = dashboardSericeManager.GetList(d => d.INSTITUTIONID != null 
                && institutionList.Any(x => d.INSTITUTIONID.Contains(x)), null).ToList();
```